# EM score in SQuAD Challenge

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, stanford-nlp, reinforcement-learning

The [SQuAD Challenge](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/) ranks the results against the F1 and EM scores. There is a lot of information about the F1 score (a function of precision and recall). But what would the EM score be?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **Exact match.** This  metric  measures  the  percentage of predictions
> that  match any one of the ground truth answers exactly.

According to [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05250.pdf).